# Modifying Pine script for stock trading

Tags: pine-script, trading

I don't know absolutely anything about pine script, I don't even know any programing language.

I need an indicator that show through an histogram the difference between two different values exponential moving averages.

I tried to modify the script of a similar public indicator that measures, with an histogram, the difference between price and an exponential moving averages.

***Original:***

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")
emaVal = input(12, "EMA Value")
varPrice = input(ohlc4, "Price")
varEMA = ema(varPrice, emaVal)

showEMA = input(false)
showPrice = input(false)
showHistogram = input(true)

output = varPrice - varEMA

plot(showEMA ? varEMA : na, color=blue)
plot(showPrice ? varPrice : na, color=purple)
plot(showHistogram and (varPrice > varEMA) ? output : na, color=green, linewidth=4, style=histogram)
plot(showHistogram and (varEMA > varPrice) ? output : na, color=red, linewidth=4, style=histogram)
```

***What I tried to do:***

```
//@version=3
study("Hello")

emaVal = input(60, "EMA 1 Value")
emaVal = input(240, "EMA 2 Value")
varEMA = ema(emaVal, emaVal)


showHistogram = input(true)

output = emaVal2 - emaVal


plot(showHistogram and (emaVal > emaVal) ? output : na, color=green, linewidth=4, style=histogram)
plot(showHistogram and (emaVal2 > emaVal) ? output : na, color=red, linewidth=4, style=histogram)
```

Please don't freak out, I just tried to go with logic without knowing absolutely anything. Someone could help me with realizing that script?

*Bonus question:* Please can you link me a source where I can learn Pine script? I searched on google but a lot of crap and people who try to sell something. I tried with the manual by trading view but I don't know the meaning of a lot of words.

Answer (score 0):

If you have questions on the code, just ask:

```
//@version=4
study("Hello")
i_emaFastP  = input( 60,    "Fast EMA Period")
i_emaSlowP  = input(240,    "Slow EMA Period")
i_emaSrc    = input(close,  "Source", type = input.source)
i_showHist  = input(true,   "Show Histogram")
i_showEmas  = input(false,  "Show EMAs")

emaFast     = ema(i_emaSrc, i_emaFastP)
emaSlow     = ema(i_emaSrc, i_emaSlowP)
emaDelta    = emaFast - emaSlow

plot(i_showEmas ? emaFast  : na, "emaFast", color.fuchsia)
plot(i_showEmas ? emaSlow  : na, "emaSlow", color.blue)
plot(i_showHist ? emaDelta : na, "Hist",    emaDelta > 0 ? color.lime : color.red, 4, plot.style_histogram)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

well, you have `emaVal` defined twice (lines 4 and 5)...you probably meant to use `emaVal2` on line 5.

Also on line 14 you're checking if `emaVal` is greater than itself: `emaVal > emaVal` (which will always be false). I'm guessing you meant to do `emaVal > emaVal2`